# Grabbing Chunks of Data from File in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, chunks

I am scanning a error log for the keyword "warning." When I find it, there is a particular case of warning that will end information relevant to the warning with only a newline character. What I want to do is scan through this error log, find the keyword warning keep skipping down the file until I find ONLY a newline character and then once I've found it, analyze that chunk and print it out.

The format would be something like this:

```
Warning! blah
blah
blah
orange

Warning! blah
blah
red
blah

Warning!
blah
blah
blah
yellow
```

Here's my code so far: 
    use strict;
    use warnings;

```
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $count = 0;

open(LOG, "<",$file) or die "cannot open < input: $!"; 

my $line = <LOG>;
while($line ne "")
{
if($line =~ /warning/i)
{
    while($line !~/\A\n\z/)
    {
        if($line =~ /red/ || $line =~ /yellow/ ||$line =~ /black/)
        {
            $count++; 
        }
        print($line);
        $line = <LOG>; 
    }
    print("Just finished a chunk.\n");
}

$line = <LOG>;
}
print($fix, "\n");
```

However, it's an infinite loop that constantly throws errors and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read file by "chunks" and not by lines

```
local $/ = "\n\n";
while(my $chunk = <LOG>) { 
  .. 
  print("Just finished a chunk.\n");
}
```

Comment: How does the variable $/ effect the statement in the while?

Comment: `$chunk` gets filled with multiple lines, and reads them until it comes to two `\n\n` chars.

Comment: Sorry, a little new to perl. "chunk" isn't a special keyword, is it? Or is the keyword: "$/" refer to the "variable I'm going to define next"?

Comment: `$/` is input record separator, and by default it's set to `\n` so in while loop you can read file line by line. It can be changed to another value, ie. two newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You enter an infinite loop because when you reach the end of file and `$line` is undefined, the expression

```
$line !~/\A\n\z/
```

is still true. You could try something like

```
    ...
    while (defined($line) && $line !~ /\A\n\z/) {
       ...
```

instead.

Comment: So that fixed the infinite loop it looks like. However, now I'm getting "Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ./chunk.pl line 12, <LOG> line 13."

Line 12 refers to: if($line =~ /warning/i)

Comment: Ah, line wasn't initialized, I got it.